# Spark Scala VectorAssembler IllegalArgumentException: XX does not exist. Available: number

Tags: scala, apache-spark, runtime-error, illegalargumentexception

I'm using Scala on Spark and I have dense matrix like this:

```
vp
```

> res63: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseMatrix =

> -0.26035262239241047   -0.9349256695883184
> 0.08719326360909431    -0.06393629243008418
> 0.006698866707269257   0.04124873027993731
> 0.011979122705128064   -0.005430767154896149
> 0.049075485175059275   0.04810618828561001
> 0.001605411530424612   0.015016736357799364
> 0.9587151228619724     -0.2534046936998956
> -0.04668498310146597   0.06015550772431999
> -0.022360873382091598  -0.22147143481166376
> -0.014153052584280682  -0.025947327705852636

I want use VectorAssembler to create feature column so I transform vp:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

val c = vp.toArray.toSeq
val vp_df = c.toDF("number")
vp_df.createOrReplaceTempView("vp_df")

val vp_list = vp_df.collect.map(_.toSeq).flatten
val vp_string = vp_list.map(_.toString)

vp_string
```

> res64: Array[String] = Array(-0.26035262239241047, 0.08719326360909431, 0.006698866707269257, 0.011979122705128064, 0.049075485175059275, 0.001605411530424612, 0.9587151228619724, -0.04668498310146597, -0.022360873382091598, -0.014153052584280682, -0.9349256695883184, -0.06393629243008418, 0.04124873027993731, -0.005430767154896149, 0.04810618828561001, 0.015016736357799364, -0.2534046936998956, 0.06015550772431999, -0.22147143481166376, -0.025947327705852636)

Then I use VectorAssembler:

```
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(vp_string).setOutputCol("features")

val output = assembler.transform(vp_df)
output.select("features").show(false)
```

But I have an error and I don't understand why

> IllegalArgumentException: -0.26035262239241047 does not exist. Available: number

I don't know how this is possible, I've done the AssemblerVector several times and this is the first time I've seen this

Comment: Because you are saying to VectorAssemblar that the cols to assemble are the float numbers of the list, and I doubt that there is a column named -0.26035262239241047

Answer (score 0):

Your "number" column is already in an array of double, so all you need is to convert this column into a dense vector.

```scala
val arrayToVectorUDF = udf((array : Seq[Double]) => {
  Vectors.dense(array.toArray)
})

vp_df.withColumn("vector", arrayToVectorUDF(col("number")))
```

**Update**: I misunderstood your code.
The `number` column is a DoubleType column, so all you need to do is pass the column name to the vector assembler.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseMatrix
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors

val data = (1 to 20).map(_.toDouble).toArray
val dm = new DenseMatrix(2, 10, data)
val vp_df = dm.toArray.toSeq.toDF("number")
val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("number")).setOutputCol("features")
val output = assembler.transform(vp_df)
output.select("features").show(false)
```

```
+--------+
|features|
+--------+
|[1.0]   |
|[2.0]   |
|[3.0]   |
|[4.0]   |
|[5.0]   |
|[6.0]   |
|[7.0]   |
|[8.0]   |
|[9.0]   |
|[10.0]  |
|[11.0]  |
|[12.0]  |
|[13.0]  |
|[14.0]  |
|[15.0]  |
|[16.0]  |
|[17.0]  |
|[18.0]  |
|[19.0]  |
|[20.0]  |
+--------+
```

Comment: I don't understand what this code does exactly but if I run it I get:


'AnalysisException: need an array field but got double'